# C# WPF control datetime up down

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, controls

Does anyone know the WPF control like DateTimeUpDown from Extended [WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimeUpDown&referringTitle=Home) but deployed as a separated control.

I'd like to use such a control but without need to incorporate quite big package like Extended WPF Toolkit.

Comment: This is a seperated control.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you elaborate it.

Comment: I modified question. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

How about WPF Control [DatePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) or custom [Calender](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx)?
With some customization you might achieve the same as the the datetimeupdown.

Please have a look on this too : [Customizing the DatePicker Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx)